# Check if a String corresponds to another String

Tags: java, string

```
String line = "1_25";
String[] data1 = new String[]{"1","26"};
String[] data2 = new String[]{"1","25"};
```

Given String `line`, I need to check if the first element of String `data1` (`data2`) coincides with the number BEFORE "_" in the String `line` and the second symbol coincides with the number AFTER "_".

For instance, in case of `data1` the number 1 passes the check, while the number 26 does not coincide with 25.

How can I do this?

Comment: new String[]{1,26}; isn't legal Java....

Comment: as @Adam meantion your syntax is invalis, but suppose yoou were trying to show concept to us. split your line into tokens and compare each token to item in your data array

Comment: Class [`java.lang.String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) contains many useful methods for string manipulation. Look in the API documentation and see what you can use to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with combination of String.split() and Arrays.equals()

- String.split() creates an array of two elements
- Arrays.equals() compares two arrays element by element

Example

```
String line = "1_25";
String[] data1 = new String[] { "1", "26" };
String[] data2 = new String[] { "1", "25" };

String[] parts = line.split("_");
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(parts, data1));
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(parts, data2));
```

Output

```
false
true
```

Answer (score 1):

Just split the string at the '_':

```
String[] linedata = line.split('_');
```

Now, compare the arrays:

```
if (Arrays.equals(data1, linedata)
    // data 1 matches
else
    // data 2 matches
```